# $L^p$ estimate for perturbed heat equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Let us consider the heat equation
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t + f(u)_x - u_{xx} = 0 & x \in (-1,1), \quad t >0\\
u(t,-1) = a(t), \\
u(t,1) = b(t), \\
u(0,x) = u_0(x)
\end{cases}
$$
where $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$. How can I estimate the quantity
$$
\partial_t \int_{-1}^1 |u|^{p-1} dx =- \int_{-1}^1 p f(u)_x |u|^{p-1} dx + \int_{-1}^1 p|u|^{p-1} u_{xx}dx
$$
for $p >1$?

Comment: When you say $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, does that implicitly mean that $f'$ is uniformly bounded?

Comment: @WillieWong Sure, we can assume that too.